# Cannot Switch PHP Version On Wamp 3.1.3

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to switch the version of PHP on my Wamp Server (3.1.3) but it keeps switching back to the old version. I have the old php version 5.x and then the new versions 7.x.
I don't work on PHP much so did not realize that occasionally when I had to do work I was using 5.x. I already have PHP 7.x version installed and I believe at some point this used to work but I might be wrong. Anyways so after switching I see all services are restarted but then when I check the PHP version, it still shows that old one as selected. So I decided to start from scratch and downloaded a new version and did the following:

1- Resaved php.ini-development file as php.ini and phpForApache.ini

2- Copied wampserver.conf from an older installation to the new php installation folder

3- Checked the dll references in wampserver.conf. They seem to be correct, pointing to php7apache2_4

I exited WAMP and start it backup and I don't even see the new version in the list. What am I doing wrong here? I also deleted one of the folder for php versions yet it continues to show in the menu. Restarted my machine and it is still there. Something seems seriously wrong here. Is there a place where I have modify these manually?

Below is what I see on localhost in case it gives out any clues

[image: wamp server]

Comment: And none of your addons depend on PHP5? (Also, wampserver is currently at 3.1.9)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't even know what addons mean w.r.t wamp.It's been a while I worked in this env for php I did not install anything else form what I remember so don't think I have any addons. And yes guess it's an older version. I had a legacy project that I had lots of issues setting up and once that started to run I did not want to touch anything especially the wamp server.

Comment: I do feel it's because of the wamp server version. Guess if I upgrade I will have to upgrade MySQL also, Is there a guide somewhere I can follow to upgrade? I posted picture of my localhost

Comment: googling "wampserver upgrade PHP" gives plenty of hits but http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/ looks fairly useful.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually the latest Full release of WAMPServer is 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

First, using [WAMPManager backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) download and run the **"Wampserver update 3.2.3"**. Its a cumulative update that works for any previous version from 3.0.3 and above. This will only update the wampmanager (the menu system in the system tray) and the scripts that it runs. **It will not affect the versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP/..... you are using.**

Second, go back to [WAMPManager backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and download the **"Checks VC++ packages installed"** This downloads an exe and that will quickly check you have all the required MSVC Runtime libraries installed for the oldest and newest versions of any of the Apache/MySQL/PHP versions that can be downloaded with WAMPManager.

If it reports you are missing any MSVC Runtime, and I expect it will if you have not used WAMPServer recently, download "All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)" (I assume you have a 64bit Windows) or the 32bit versions if you dont. If you are using a 64bit WAMPServer on a 64bit windows install the 32bit & 64bit runtime.

This will download a zip file, unzip it into a folder somewhere and run ALL of the `vcresist.exe` files, One by One from oldest version to newest version. If the dialog appears saying that you already have this version, it is best to use the REPAIR option to ensure thay are all in good condition.

Now you have a good base to run any version of Apache/MySQL/PHP etc that you could possibly want to use.

So thirdly, go back to the [WAMPManager backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and now download any of the ADDON versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP etc taht you want to run. The install of any new ADDON will stop WAMPServer, so relaunch WAMPServer and switch to the version of whichever ADDON you downloaded.